# Difference between placing a server behind a DMZ vs directly behind a WAN

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, dmz

My ISP provides a block of 5 IPs. I have an 8 port switch that my ISP is connected to, and one of the ports goes to my Ubiquiti Edgerouter to provide Internet access to my home PCs.

I recently bought a server and wanted to make it accessible over the Internet. From what I read, it seems placing it behind a DMZ is a better idea than plugging it directly into the WAN switch and assigning it a public IP. But why?

The server in reference will run a flavor of Linux, most likely Debian or CentOS. I will be using iptables to create a restricted firewall, only allowing access to the ports needed to run my services. I will have clamav, rkhunter, and tripwire configured to check and send alerts. No unused services will be installed or accessible.

How does the DMZ really help in this case? Isn't the DMZ doing the same thing as iptables? Except instead of the server taking the hit of port scanning, the router will.

Comment: If there's no other computers on the LAN (just the server) then you don't need a DMZ (or even a router).  The [first couple/few paragraphs on Wikipedia's DMZ article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) explain the purpose pretty clearly.

Comment: I plan on keeping the server on it's own - no LAN for it.

Comment: Then you don't need a DMZ, as you have no internal LAN to protect. :) What is it that you read that suggested you should have one?

Comment: Connecting it to the WAN switch, and putting it behind a DMZ, it basically doing the exact samething.  Any and all traffic will reach the server, and that is obviously a horrible idea, so neither idea is a good idea.  You can put it behind a router, give that router the public address, and make the server accessible to the internet on only certain ports.

Comment: Wouldn't iptables do the same as the router - protect all ports except the ones that need to be allowed through? It seems like I'm adding hardware and failure points without gaining anything - unless I'm missing something.